# wlan0 not created when using Ubuntu 19.10 netboot (HP Notebook 14-cf1599sa with Intel Wireless-AC 9461)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 on an [HP Notebook 14-cf1599sa](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c06326583) using the [mini.iso netboot image](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/) for amd64.

I only have a Wi-Fi internet connection available, but the netboot isn't creating a network adapter for me to configure — I expected `wlan0` or similar, but it doesn't exist. The computer contains Intel Wireless-AC 9461 hardware, and the `iwlwifi` driver does appear to be loading successfully, including its firmware:

```
~ # dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    2.379659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.379661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.379887] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

But only the loopback and wired network adapters are present:

```
~ # ipconfig -a
eno1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 04:0e:3c:d4:90:fb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The netboot is running a recent Linux kernel version that should support this card:

```
~ # uname -a
Linux (none) 5.3.0-18-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 8 20:14:06 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output from `lspci -knn`:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0264]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Running `rfkill list` did not output anything.

Some further information: I've put the output of `modinfo iwlwifi` [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/DeMcYhKF), and the full `dmesg` output [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/gKN4a7Eh).

I have no idea what else to try here. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I've added this extra information. Thanks for helping me ask a better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this myself.

It turns out the the `iwlmvm` driver is not present on the netboot mini.iso, and this is required, in combination with the `iwlwifi` driver, to get the hardware working.

I used the following steps to resolve this:

1. On a separate computer, download the [linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-18-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-18-generic) package for amd64. This matches the kernel version present on the netboot iso.

   - This was a file named `linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-18-generic_5.3.0-18.19_amd64.deb`.
2. Extract the .deb file and copy the file `lib/modules/5.3.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko` to some removable storage.
3. On the computer running the netboot installer, start a shell (e.g. via main menu, or pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 or similar) and mount the removable storage on `/mnt`.
4. Run `modprobe mac80211`.
5. Run `insmod /mnt/iwlmvm.ko`.
6. Continue the installation — the network should now be recognised.

Comment: Also it looks like this bug may be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1848236